# How to create a function with zipWithIndex that returns an Int from a List[Int] in scala

Tags: user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I'm trying to use **zipWithIndex** to index of the first negative value in my List by creating a method function that takes a **List[Int]** and will return an **Int** or an option[Int] for me to use. First, I created the list and the function with **zipWithIndex**  but I keep getting type mismatch error:

```
val list = List(-2,-1,2,3,4)

def getNegativeIndex(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  
    for ((x, count) <- xs.zipWithIndex if x < 0) yield(count)
}
```

and this is the error I keep getting:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int] => Int
 required: Int
```

My aim is to index off the first negative value of the List **"list"**
i.e my result should be getNegativeIndex(list) == 0 using the list I provided since the 1st element -2 is at index 0

pls, what do I need to add to the above function or remove to achieve my goal

Comment: `zipWithIndex` doesn't take an argument. So, when you do `list.zipWithIndex(getNegativeIndex(_))` it will expect an integer because it's equivalent to `list.zipWithIndex.apply(getNegativeIndex(_))`.
But maybe for clarification, could you provide the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @Yann. From the list I provided, my desired output should be (-2, 0), where -2 is the 1st negative element in the list and 0 is the index.

Comment: sorry, it should return index 0 using the provided List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `getNegativeIndex(list)` to return a single integer and your desired value you need to only return the `headOption` of the list that your for-comprehension generates.

The current for-comprehension is equivalent to
`xs.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 < 0).map(_._2)`. So you can either do this

```
xs.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 < 0).map(_._2).headOption
```

Or add the `headOption` to your comprehension like this

```
(
  for ((x, count) <- xs.zipWithIndex if x < 0) yield(count)
).headOption
```

The result will be the same, i.e. the function returns the first index of a negative number in the list or `None` if all are non-negative. You could instead use `.head` to get an integer directly but be aware that it will throw an exception if the list doesn't contain any negative number or is empty.